# Disambiguation of the toilet tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that the [toilet](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet) tag is currently used for two different purposes:

1. questions about locations or objects used for urination and defication, e.g. [composting toilets](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/3076/99)
2. questions about personal hygiene, e.g. [using deodorant](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/247/99).

What do you think? Is this double use of the toilet tag ok, or should we  separate the 2 uses?

In case of the latter, we should probably rename the toilet tag to make it less ambiguous and introduce a new second tag. What would be good names?

Comment: Since we now have a [tag:personal-hygiene] tag I cleaned up all questions where the [tag:toilet] tag was misused for questions on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

Since users will still search toilet, perhaps it's best to make compound tags - such as **toilet-lavatory** and **toilet-hygiene**?

Answer (score 0):

I like LShaver's answer, but at the same time I'm afraid that people will use a **toilet-hygiene** tag solely for questions about cleaning their toilet. Perhaps it's better to introduce a new tag called **grooming** or **personal-hygiene** since those terms cover the topic very well. We can refer to this new tag in the existing [toilet](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet) tag.

If the toilet tag continues to be misused after the introduction of a new tag, we can still change the tag name (to sanitation for example)